# .net 4.x framework and asp.net core 2.2 application on same domain

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server

I am currently going through the process of converting a prior application that lives on apps.website.com from .Net 4.5 to .Net Core 2.2.

As this is a WIP, I would like to publish each component as it is completed.  Is it possible for a .Net 4.X framework application to coexist on the same domain (apps.website.com) as the new ASP.NET Core 2.2 application?

In an ideal world, if a request were made to apps.website.com/forms/contact, a proxy would be able to check the .NET core 2.2 application to see if it can serve the request -- if not, then utilize the older, .net framework application.

In a sense, a fallback that checks Core first, .Net 4.X next (if needed)

Comment: apps.website.com/app1 apps.website.com/app2 or how?

Comment: @gsharp Thanks.  I added another paragraph to my original question.

Comment: No problem at all.  You can have two applications in the same web site, that use different Application Pools and are totally independent.